# java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getEmail()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I wanted to show user email on homepage with a textview I tried to get email by using `getCurrentUser().getEmail()` but it showed me an error

> > java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getEmail()' on a null object reference

Here is the code

```
public class Homepage extends AppCompatActivity {
protected FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
@Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
       TextView tt1 = findViewById(R.id.tt1);
        String email = auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
        tt1.setText(email);
    }
}
```

Login.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private Button btnSignup, btnLogin, btnReset;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Homepage.class));
            finish();
        }

        // set the view now
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, SignUp.class));
            }
        });

        btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, ResetPassword.class));
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                //authenticate user
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(Login.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.

                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // there was an error
                                    if (password.length() < 6) {
                                        inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Homepage.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name=".Login"> <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter></activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

If user has not logged in then auth.getCurrentUser() will return null. You have to put a check `if(auth.getCurrentUser() != null){
 String email = auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
 tt1.setText(email); 
}`

Comment: Yea it has proved that the user has not logged in but I don't think my code for login class has any error maybe you can take a look on that I have uploaded the login.java

Comment: what are the ways for a user to lend on home page and which is your launch activity? can you verify launch activity from manifest?

Comment: ```Login.java``` will be the launch activity and after logging in it will redirect to home page and that's the only way to access to home page if the user has not logged in it will brings you back to the login page